# Why using this sample on my Galaxy Nexus camera is slow?

Tags: android, eclipse

The code i took it from this link :

```
http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/index.html
```

The project: Color Histograms
Its working good showing histograms in real time on my device .

The problem is that if i'm using my device camera regulary it's moving fast and smooth i mean i'm moving my device around without recording video or taking photos and it's moving smooth fast.

But once i'm using this project and show the histograms in real time it's much slowly .

The question is why ? And if there is any way to make it smoother and faster ?

This is the main code:

```
package com.example.viewfinderee368;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

public class ViewfinderEE368 extends Activity {    
    private Preview mPreview;
    private DrawOnTop mDrawOnTop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Hide the window title.
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        // Create our DrawOnTop view.
        mDrawOnTop = new DrawOnTop(this);
        mPreview = new Preview(this, mDrawOnTop);
        setContentView(mPreview);
        addContentView(mDrawOnTop, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class DrawOnTop extends View {
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    Paint mPaintBlack;
    Paint mPaintYellow;
    Paint mPaintRed;
    Paint mPaintGreen;
    Paint mPaintBlue;
    byte[] mYUVData;
    int[] mRGBData;
    int mImageWidth, mImageHeight;
    int[] mRedHistogram;
    int[] mGreenHistogram;
    int[] mBlueHistogram;
    double[] mBinSquared;

    public DrawOnTop(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mPaintBlack = new Paint();
        mPaintBlack.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaintBlack.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaintBlack.setTextSize(25);

        mPaintYellow = new Paint();
        mPaintYellow.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaintYellow.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        mPaintYellow.setTextSize(25);

        mPaintRed = new Paint();
        mPaintRed.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaintRed.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaintRed.setTextSize(25);

        mPaintGreen = new Paint();
        mPaintGreen.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaintGreen.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        mPaintGreen.setTextSize(25);

        mPaintBlue = new Paint();
        mPaintBlue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaintBlue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        mPaintBlue.setTextSize(25);

        mBitmap = null;
        mYUVData = null;
        mRGBData = null;
        mRedHistogram = new int[256];
        mGreenHistogram = new int[256];
        mBlueHistogram = new int[256];
        mBinSquared = new double[256];
        for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
        {
            mBinSquared[bin] = ((double)bin) * bin;
        } // bin
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mBitmap != null)
        {
            int canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
            int canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();
            int newImageWidth = canvasWidth;
            int newImageHeight = canvasHeight;
            int marginWidth = (canvasWidth - newImageWidth)/2;

            // Convert from YUV to RGB
            decodeYUV420SP(mRGBData, mYUVData, mImageWidth, mImageHeight);

            // Draw bitmap
            mBitmap.setPixels(mRGBData, 0, mImageWidth, 0, 0, 
                    mImageWidth, mImageHeight);
            Rect src = new Rect(0, 0, mImageWidth, mImageHeight);
            Rect dst = new Rect(marginWidth, 0, 
                    canvasWidth-marginWidth, canvasHeight);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, src, dst, mPaintBlack);

            // Draw black borders                       
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, marginWidth, canvasHeight, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawRect(canvasWidth - marginWidth, 0, 
                    canvasWidth, canvasHeight, mPaintBlack);

            // Calculate histogram
            calculateIntensityHistogram(mRGBData, mRedHistogram, 
                    mImageWidth, mImageHeight, 0);
            calculateIntensityHistogram(mRGBData, mGreenHistogram, 
                    mImageWidth, mImageHeight, 1);
            calculateIntensityHistogram(mRGBData, mBlueHistogram, 
                    mImageWidth, mImageHeight, 2);

            // Calculate mean
            double imageRedMean = 0, imageGreenMean = 0, imageBlueMean = 0;
            double redHistogramSum = 0, greenHistogramSum = 0, blueHistogramSum = 0;
            for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
            {
                imageRedMean += mRedHistogram[bin] * bin;
                redHistogramSum += mRedHistogram[bin];
                imageGreenMean += mGreenHistogram[bin] * bin;
                greenHistogramSum += mGreenHistogram[bin];
                imageBlueMean += mBlueHistogram[bin] * bin;
                blueHistogramSum += mBlueHistogram[bin];
            } // bin
            imageRedMean /= redHistogramSum;
            imageGreenMean /= greenHistogramSum;
            imageBlueMean /= blueHistogramSum;

            // Calculate second moment
            double imageRed2ndMoment = 0, imageGreen2ndMoment = 0, imageBlue2ndMoment = 0;
            for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
            {
                imageRed2ndMoment += mRedHistogram[bin] * mBinSquared[bin];
                imageGreen2ndMoment += mGreenHistogram[bin] * mBinSquared[bin];
                imageBlue2ndMoment += mBlueHistogram[bin] * mBinSquared[bin];
            } // bin
            imageRed2ndMoment /= redHistogramSum;
            imageGreen2ndMoment /= greenHistogramSum;
            imageBlue2ndMoment /= blueHistogramSum;
            double imageRedStdDev = Math.sqrt( imageRed2ndMoment - imageRedMean*imageRedMean );
            double imageGreenStdDev = Math.sqrt( imageGreen2ndMoment - imageGreenMean*imageGreenMean );
            double imageBlueStdDev = Math.sqrt( imageBlue2ndMoment - imageBlueMean*imageBlueMean );

            // Draw mean
            String imageMeanStr = "Mean (R,G,B): " + String.format("%.4g", imageRedMean) + ", " + String.format("%.4g", imageGreenMean) + ", " + String.format("%.4g", imageBlueMean);
            canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10-1, 30-1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10+1, 30-1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10+1, 30+1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10-1, 30+1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10, 30, mPaintYellow);

            // Draw standard deviation
            String imageStdDevStr = "Std Dev (R,G,B): " + String.format("%.4g", imageRedStdDev) + ", " + String.format("%.4g", imageGreenStdDev) + ", " + String.format("%.4g", imageBlueStdDev);
            canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10-1, 60-1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10+1, 60-1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10+1, 60+1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10-1, 60+1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10, 60, mPaintYellow);

            // Draw red intensity histogram
            float barMaxHeight = 3000;
            float barWidth = ((float)newImageWidth) / 256;
            float barMarginHeight = 2;
            RectF barRect = new RectF();
            barRect.bottom = canvasHeight - 200;
            barRect.left = marginWidth;
            barRect.right = barRect.left + barWidth;
            for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
            {
                float prob = (float)mRedHistogram[bin] / (float)redHistogramSum;
                barRect.top = barRect.bottom - 
                    Math.min(80,prob*barMaxHeight) - barMarginHeight;
                canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlack);
                barRect.top += barMarginHeight;
                canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintRed);
                barRect.left += barWidth;
                barRect.right += barWidth;
            } // bin

            // Draw green intensity histogram
            barRect.bottom = canvasHeight - 100;
            barRect.left = marginWidth;
            barRect.right = barRect.left + barWidth;
            for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
            {
                barRect.top = barRect.bottom - Math.min(80, ((float)mGreenHistogram[bin])/((float)greenHistogramSum) * barMaxHeight) - barMarginHeight;
                canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlack);
                barRect.top += barMarginHeight;
                canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintGreen);
                barRect.left += barWidth;
                barRect.right += barWidth;
            } // bin

            // Draw blue intensity histogram
            barRect.bottom = canvasHeight;
            barRect.left = marginWidth;
            barRect.right = barRect.left + barWidth;
            for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
            {
                barRect.top = barRect.bottom - Math.min(80, ((float)mBlueHistogram[bin])/((float)blueHistogramSum) * barMaxHeight) - barMarginHeight;
                canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlack);
                barRect.top += barMarginHeight;
                canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlue);
                barRect.left += barWidth;
                barRect.right += barWidth;
            } // bin
        } // end if statement

        super.onDraw(canvas);

    } // end onDraw method

    static public void decodeYUV420SP(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height) {
        final int frameSize = width * height;

        for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
            int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
                int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;
                if (y < 0) y = 0;
                if ((i & 1) == 0) {
                    v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                    u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                }

                int y1192 = 1192 * y;
                int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
                int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
                int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

                if (r < 0) r = 0; else if (r > 262143) r = 262143;
                if (g < 0) g = 0; else if (g > 262143) g = 262143;
                if (b < 0) b = 0; else if (b > 262143) b = 262143;

                rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);
            }
        }
    }

    static public void decodeYUV420SPGrayscale(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height)
    {
        final int frameSize = width * height;

        for (int pix = 0; pix < frameSize; pix++)
        {
            int pixVal = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[pix])) - 16;
            if (pixVal < 0) pixVal = 0;
            if (pixVal > 255) pixVal = 255;
            rgb[pix] = 0xff000000 | (pixVal << 16) | (pixVal << 8) | pixVal;
        } // pix
    }

    static public void calculateIntensityHistogram(int[] rgb, int[] histogram, int width, int height, int component)
    {
        for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
        {
            histogram[bin] = 0;
        } // bin
        if (component == 0) // red
        {
            for (int pix = 0; pix < width*height; pix += 3)
            {
                int pixVal = (rgb[pix] >> 16) & 0xff;
                histogram[ pixVal ]++;
            } // pix
        }
        else if (component == 1) // green
        {
            for (int pix = 0; pix < width*height; pix += 3)
            {
                int pixVal = (rgb[pix] >> 8) & 0xff;
                histogram[ pixVal ]++;
            } // pix
        }
        else // blue
        {
            for (int pix = 0; pix < width*height; pix += 3)
            {
                int pixVal = rgb[pix] & 0xff;
                histogram[ pixVal ]++;
            } // pix
        }
    }
} 

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    Camera mCamera;
    DrawOnTop mDrawOnTop;
    boolean mFinished;

    Preview(Context context, DrawOnTop drawOnTop) {
        super(context);

        mDrawOnTop = drawOnTop;
        mFinished = false;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        try {
           mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

           // Preview callback used whenever new viewfinder frame is available
           mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
              public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
              {
                  if ( (mDrawOnTop == null) || mFinished )
                      return;

                  if (mDrawOnTop.mBitmap == null)
                  {
                      // Initialize the draw-on-top companion
                      Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
                      mDrawOnTop.mImageWidth = params.getPreviewSize().width;
                      mDrawOnTop.mImageHeight = params.getPreviewSize().height;
                      mDrawOnTop.mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mDrawOnTop.mImageWidth, 
                              mDrawOnTop.mImageHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                      mDrawOnTop.mRGBData = new int[mDrawOnTop.mImageWidth * mDrawOnTop.mImageHeight]; 
                      mDrawOnTop.mYUVData = new byte[data.length];                    
                  }

                  // Pass YUV data to draw-on-top companion
                  System.arraycopy(data, 0, mDrawOnTop.mYUVData, 0, data.length);
                  mDrawOnTop.invalidate();
              }
           });
        } 
        catch (IOException exception) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
        // important to release it when the activity is paused.
        mFinished = true;
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
        // the preview.
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(320, 240);
        parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(15);
        parameters.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_NIGHT);
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of direct drawing to the screen.  Generally its faster to draw to a bitmap, then just transfer the bitmap to the screen in onDraw.  Also, your onDraw is huge-  you want that to be small and fast, doing as much of the calculations ahead of time as possible.  You also want to avoid instantiating objects in onDraw or any functions called from it-  that takes time.

Basically the code is functional but not written for efficiency.  Typical of anything from a school project (yes, that includes most code written by TAs/profs),